# expect script timing out

Tags: linux, ssh

First time use of expect to collect data from routers
I have just added a single simple command pwd
Wnen running through list of routers at times it would only execute one pwd
Ps  I do include more complex commands but trying to keep it simple with just a single pwd

Have tried used the various commands in script with but not much luck
Appreciate if you could give us an idea where I might best put the commands shown in black bold
Or perhaps a better method of scripting
Also not sure why it spits out the messages at the end of the for loop shown in red at the bottom of the output

Thanks in advance
Mik
N BOLD
I
    "exp_internal 1" debug
    wait
    Set timeout 60
    Sleep 10

```
Expect connect to routers and collect info
Host2.txt  list of routers

#!/usr/local/bin/expect

set f [open "host2.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f


foreach host $hosts {
eval spawn /usr/local/bin/ssh -l userid $host

expect "Password:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
send "pwd\r"
send "pwd\r"
send "pwd\r"
send "exit\r"
expect "closed\r"
}
```

Comment: “exp_internal 1" debug
wait
Set timeout 60
Sleep 10

Comment: $ expect_script_sh
spawn /usr/local/bin/ssh -l userid router
userid@router1’s password: 
>>>> All commands in script /usr/.profile were successful
…
Router1# spawn /usr/local/bin/ssh -l userid
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgkMNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tu ....